Image of a sector under a polynomial $P(z)$
Let $P(z)=a_0+a_1z+\cdots+a_dz^d$ be a polynomial where $a_i\in\mathbb{C}\setminus{\mathbb{R}}^-$ for $i=0,1,...,d$ with $a_d\neq 0$. Consider the sector $A=\{c\in\mathbb{C}:\beta\leq Arg(z)\leq \frac{\pi}{2}\}$ where $Arg(z)$ denotes the principal argument of $z$. We can choose this sector to be sufficiently thin by taking $\beta$ close to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Also, consider a disk $D(0,R)$ of sufficiently large radius $R$ and take $B=A\setminus D(0,R)$.
Question: Does the image $P(B)$ lie inside a sector with a small opening (means, the argument of $P(z)$ does not vary too much in the image sector for all $z$ in $B$)?
My attempt
We know that the polynomial $P$ acts as a monomial near $\infty$ i.e., $P(z)\sim z^d$, and the map $z\mapsto z^d$ maps $B$ inside a sector ( I have checked). This intuition says that this can be true for $P$ also.
Consider the ray $R_\theta=\{z=re^{i\theta}:r>0\}$ for $\theta\in[\beta,\frac{\pi}{2}]$. Note that $Arg(P(z))=Arg(z^d)+Arg\left(\frac{P(z)}{z^d}\right)=dArg(z)+Arg\left(\frac{P(Re^{i\theta})}{R^d e^{id\theta}}\right)$ for all $z\neq 0$ and the limit $\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac{P(z)}{z^d}$ along $R_\theta$ is
$\lim_{r\to\infty} \frac{P(re^{i\theta})}{r^d e^{id\theta}}=\lim_{r\to\infty}\frac{1}{e^{id\theta}}(a_de^{id\theta}+a_{d-1}\frac{e^{i(d-1)\theta}}{r}+\cdots
 +\frac{a_1e^{i\theta}}{r^{d-1}}+\frac{a_0}{r^d})=a_d$. Since the principal argument is a continuous function in $\mathbb C\setminus\mathbb{R}^-$, along $R_\theta$ we get $$\lim_{|z|\to\infty}Arg(P(z))=d\theta+Arg(a_d).$$  Therefore for a fixed $\epsilon>0$ sufficiently small and any ray $R_\theta$, there exists a finite $M_\theta>0$ such that for $|z|>M_\theta $,
\begin{equation}
 |Arg(P(z))-\{d\theta+Arg(a_d)\}|<\epsilon.
    \end{equation}
Now take the infimum of these $M_\theta$'s and denote $\widetilde{M}_\theta=\inf \{M_\theta: M_\theta$ corresponds to $R_\theta\}$.
Now I want to show that the set $K=\{\widetilde{M_\theta} :\beta\leq\theta\leq\frac{\pi}{2}\}$ is bounded. Then we shall have, $P(B)$ is contained in a sector with opening $d|\frac{\pi}{2}-\beta|$ (i.e., the principal arguments of the two lines emanating from the origin and bounding the sector differ at most by $d|\frac{\pi}{2}-\beta|$). But I can't prove that the set $K$ is bounded.
Can anyone suggest me how $K$ is bounded?
Is my justification correct? Any comments or directions (any other approach) will be highly appreciated.

Looks correct - the argument function is uniformly continuous away from zero so looking at $P(z)/(a_dz^d)$ which is uniformly close to $1$ in the given sector and large $z$ you can conclude
